# Calculate the ratio of heat losses from two different bodies at different temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics

[image]

In the above question, I used Newton law of cooling, and got answer 3:2, but this option is not given in the above question. What is the correct method to solve this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is asked 'heat loss' not temperature loss.
Use Stefan's law instead:
$\frac {dQ} {dt}= \sigma \epsilon A(T^4-T_0^4)$
So rate of heat loss is proportional to $T^4-T_0^4$ ($T_0$ is temperature of surroundings)

So, calculating $\frac {327^4-27^4} {227^4-27^4}$ comes out to be nearly 4

Comment: Those are the initial *rates* of heat loss, not the heat losses themselves.  If the bodies are identical (except for their initial temperatures) and their heat capacities don't depend on temperature, then the OP's answer is correct.  In addition, in your equation, T should be the absolute temperature, not the centigrade temperature.

Comment: Since in the above question, there is a huge  temperature difference, so Stephan's law will work here? As you said it is only for initial rates of heat losses. Which formula will describe it's behaviour afterwards @ChetMiller

Comment: Like I said, in my judgment, your original answer of 3:2 was correct, and that is closest to answer (a).  By the way, you are aware that Stefan's law is supposed to use Absolute Temperatures, so Singh's answer is incorrect on that score also.